# How to get Json object from GETrequest in FLASK

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, flask

My server is flask, my client is javascript, i'm using jquery - ajax to send data to the server. I am able to get JSON objects from a POST request but unable to do so with a GET.

request from Javascript Client:

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET',
        url: "/checkForTrain",
        data: jsonObj,
        success: function(response){
            response = JSON.parse(response)
            if(response['status']==='success')
                postDataset(data)
            else
                handleError(data)
        },
        error :   function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
```

url to handle request in flask:

```
@app.route('/checkForTrain',methods=['GET','OPTIONS'])
def checkForTrain():
    print request
    json_str=u''+str(request.get_data())
    print json_str,' <--- json data'
    dataSearch = json.loads(json_str)
    print dataSearch,' <--- dictionary'
    obj = dbWrapper.checkForTrain(dataSearch['name'],dataSearch['type'])
    return obj
```

Output from print request:

```
<Request 'http://localhost:5000/checkForTrain?{"name":"lel","technique":"regression"}' [GET]>
```

Output from print json_str,' <--- json data'

```
<--- json data
```

Stacktrace for server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/adminuser/Desktop/Github/DataMining/DataMiningProject/app/routes.py", line 53, in checkForTrain
    dataSearch = json.loads(json_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the *query string*; you can use the [`request.query_string` attribute](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.query_string) to access it; you'll have to manually [unquote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) it:

```
From urllib import unquote

json_str = unquote(request.query_string)
```

Your view then outputs:

```
<Request 'http://localhost:5000/checkForTrain?{"name":"lel","technique":"regression"}' [GET]>
{"name":"lel","technique":"regression"}  <--- json data
{u'technique': u'regression', u'name': u'lel'}  <--- dictionary
```

The [`request.get_data()` method](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.get_data) can only be used to access the request *body*, and a `GET` request never has a body.

If your data consists just of key-value pairs it may be easier just to stick to form-encoding those however and stick with Flask's `request.args` functionality instead of bothering with JSON here.

Comment: thanks, however the out put is 
{%22name%22:%22ded%22,%22technique%22:%22regression%22}  <--- json data
any idea how to remove the %22's

Comment: for those who encounter my problem as well, my arguments were also wrong, like @Martijn said a Get never has a body, i was passing a JSON object as a parameter when i should have been passing the query string and my url as such should have been

http://localhost:5000/checkForTrain?name=lel&technique=regression

Comment: @Dilz: right, the value is the raw URL component so un-quoting is going to be needed; updated for that. Using regular form-encoded key-value pairs in the query string may well be simpler.